# Validity and usage =+ in PHP

Tags: php, variable-assignment, addition, assignment-operator

Take this example:

```
<?php

$i = 1;
$i += 2;
$i =+ 5;

echo $i; // 5
```

This shows that `=+` is an assignment operator. Still, this is highly confusing to me and not at all semantic. I spent hours debugging something simply because I accidentally used `=+` instead of `+=`. The former does not throw errors, though. So I am curious: what is the use case for `=+`. When would you ever (need to) use it over a simple `=`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=+` is not a single operator. Its two: the assignment (`=`) and the unary plus (`+`).

If you insert different whitespace it gets obvious:

```
$i = +5;
```

The unary plus in PHP is used for conversion of `$i` to `int` or `float` as appropriate. Since `5` already is an int, its the *identity* in this case, and the whole expression is semantically equivalent to:

```
 $i = 5;
```

Answer (score 3):

`=+` is not an operator. Think of it as

```
$i = +5;
```

as opposed to

```
$i = -5;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned **+=** is an assignment operator is correct.

In your case:

```
$i = 1;
```

Just assign the value 1 to `$i` and then when your second line execute `$i += 2;`, its just add the value 2 with the existing value of `$i`.

So now when you use `$i =+ 5;` in your third line, its **re-assign** the variable `$i` with the positive value **+5**.

There are no big deal with **=+** and **+=** these are different.